# searching a 2D int[][] array?

Tags: java, arrays, search, int, 2d

How do I search a 2D array for a specific number (1)? I thought the following code did it, but apparently I was looking in a specific spot whenI declared it with [4][4].

```
    boolean undirectedCircuit (int [][] graph)
{
    //graph = graph1(graph1(null));

    int edgeCounter = 0;

    for (int edge = 0; edge < graph.length; edge++)
    {
        /* SET FOR WHEN 1s are found in array: edgeCounter++;*/
        if(graph[4][4] == '1')
        {
            edgeCounter++;
            System.out.println("edgeCounter found '1' " + edgeCounter + "times");
        }
    }

    if (edgeCounter % 2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a circuit!");
        //return true;
    }
    else System.out.println("This is not a circuit!!");
    return false;
    }

public void go ()
{
    graph1 = new int[][] //This line is complained about.
            {
            {0,1,1,1,0},
            {1,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,1,0},
            {1,0,1,0,1},
            {0,1,0,1,0}
            };

    undirectedCircuit(graph1); //This is complained about.
}
```

This is part of an assignment from my school, just pointers would be great. Thank you!

Comment: The literal `'1'` is a character. To search for an integer, remove the single-quotes: `== 1`.

Comment: You want pointers? http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: Think about it, how would you iterate a single array, with one loop rt? and here you need to iterate through array of arrays, so you need a nested loop. Also, when your array is 4X4, you just need to search upto  graph[3][3], as the index starts from 0.

Comment: Where is `graph1` defined in `go()`? Is it an instance variable?

Comment: @August, the undirectedGraph(graph1); is passing in the graph1 to graph in undirectedGraph() method,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong in two ways:

```
 if(graph[4][4] == '1')
```

1. The quotes around `'1'` make it a `char` literal. Since your array contains `int`s, you'll want to drop the quotes and just write `1`.
2. `graph[4][4]` will always check the same value in the array as you said. Specifically, it will always access the fifth value in the fifth array of your 2d array. Whenever you write numbers in your code, they are constants: the number 4 is never going to change during your program's execution, so you keep using 4 as the index over and over again, accessing the fifth element each time you do so.

In order to access every element in an array, you can loop over it like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n ++)
{
    array[n]; //access the nth element of the array
}
```

`n` in this instance is the same as your `edge` variable.

However, since you are using a 2d array, these elements are themselves arrays! Therefore, you need another loop:

```
//array is a 2d array...

for (int n = 0; n < array.length; n ++)
{
    //...so its elements are 1d arrays
    for (int m = 0; m < array[n].length; m ++)
    {
        array[m][n]; //here we have a specific object in our 2d array.
    }
}
```

We use variables for our indices so they can change in the loop and access different values in the array. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I really appreciate it! I felt so silly when my professor told me I was going to a specific location... haha! I completely understand how this works, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this where you will iterate through both dimensions of the array and check your current location rather than the 4,4

```
for (int x = 0; x < graph.length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < graph[x].length; y++)
            {
                /* SET FOR WHEN 1s are found in array: edgeCounter++;*/
                if (graph[x][y] == 1)
                {
                    edgeCounter++;
                    System.out.println("edgeCounter found '1' " + edgeCounter + "times");
                }
            }
        }
```